# how to shutdown my ubuntu-server 16.04.2

Tags: command-line, shutdown

When I use `sudo init 0` to shutdown the system ,it always staying at

> [ok] Stopped LVM2 metadata daemon

[image: img]

What can I do？

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to shutdown, is to use the `shutdown` command.

e.g.:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

**info about shutdown**

- [shutdown man](https://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown)
- [nix Craft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/shutdown-unix/)

> `shutdown [OPTION]... TIME [MESSAGE]`
>
> `-h` Requests that the system be either halted or powered off after it has been brought down, with the choice as to which left up to the system. 
> `-H` Requests that the system be halted after it has been brought down. 
> `-P` Requests that the system be powered off after it has been brought down.

Comment: I tried these command but It's nothing to work